# Paypal Billing agreement, weird response

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

I have an issue dealing with the PayPal-PHP-SDK,

My problem is, i'm creating the plan and the agreement, everything is working fine,

I'm putting 30€ as a fee in the agreement and the plan :

```
        $amont = 30 ;   // Prix 
$merchantPreferences->setReturnUrl("$baseUrl/paiement-accept.php")
    ->setCancelUrl("$baseUrl/paiement-cancel.php")
    ->setAutoBillAmount("yes")
    ->setInitialFailAmountAction("CONTINUE")
    ->setMaxFailAttempts("0")
    ->setSetupFee(new Currency(array('value' => $amont, 'currency' => $currency)));
```

The date i'm using to create it it's :

```
$date = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', time()+210)  ."Z";`
$agreement->setName($name)
    ->setDescription($description)
    ->setStartDate($date);
```

I tried with time()+210 and using only now's timestamp.

I execute the agreement, and there is the answer :

```
{
"id": "I-VD24XJ8MG14N",
"state": "Pending",
"description": "Abonnement Mensuel - 30\u20ac/mois",
"plan": {
    "payment_definitions": [
        {
            "type": "REGULAR",
            "frequency": "Month",
            "amount": {
                "currency": "EUR",
                "value": "30.00"
            },
            "cycles": "0",
            "charge_models": [
                {
                    "type": "TAX",
                    "amount": {
                        "currency": "EUR",
                        "value": "0.00"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "SHIPPING",
                    "amount": {
                        "currency": "EUR",
                        "value": "0.00"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "frequency_interval": "1"
        }
    ],
    "merchant_preferences": {
        "setup_fee": {
            "currency": "EUR",
            "value": "0.00"
        },
        "max_fail_attempts": "0",
        "auto_bill_amount": "YES"
    }
},
"links": [
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/I-VD24XJ8MG14N/suspend",
        "rel": "suspend",
        "method": "POST"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/I-VD24XJ8MG14N/re-activate",
        "rel": "re_activate",
        "method": "POST"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/I-VD24XJ8MG14N/cancel",
        "rel": "cancel",
        "method": "POST"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/I-VD24XJ8MG14N/bill-balance",
        "rel": "self",
        "method": "POST"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/I-VD24XJ8MG14N/set-balance",
        "rel": "self",
        "method": "POST"
    }
],
"start_date": "2014-11-21T23:00:00Z",
"agreement-details": {
    "outstanding_balance": {
        "currency": "EUR",
        "value": "0.00"
    },
    "cycles_remaining": "0",
    "cycles_completed": "0",
    "final_payment_date": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "failed_payment_count": "0"
}
```

}

I don't know why the setup_fees are at 00

Why is start date at "2014-11-21T23:00:00Z"

And why is it the state Pending.

Can you help me how to make it work ? :(

If you need more informations (more code) to see where the problem is, ask me and i'll answer with more informations

Thanks a lot !

Xusifob

/***************************************************************************************************

EDIT :

****************************************************************************************************/

Thank you for taking the time of answering me.

For the date i changed it,

The payment method to create the billing agrement is a paypal account :

```
// Add Payer
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
$agreement->setPayer($payer);
```

I've already done all theses steps, click on the approval url, connect to my paypal test account and accept the transaction.

On my return page, I am on this page :

mywebsite/paiement-accept.php?token=EC-4VW6406102605853H

I've seen in the Paypal api that the ExecuteAgreement page is expecting a success value in the url ($_GET['success'] = true)

But i never got this value in my url, and the answer tell me that the User cancelled the Approval.

I changed the code not to have this error anymore and it gives me the response i put above.

This is my code :

```
$createdAgreement = require '../vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/billing/ExecuteAgreement.php';
require '../vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/billing/GetBillingAgreement.php';
```

And for the ExecuteAgreement :

```
if (isset($_GET['token'])) {

    $token = $_GET['token'];

    $agreement = new \PayPal\Api\Agreement();

    try {
        $agreement->execute($token, $apiContext);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        ResultPrinter::printError("Executed an Agreement", "Agreement", $agreement->getId(), $_GET['token'], $ex);
        exit(1);
    }
    ResultPrinter::printResult("Executed an Agreement", "Agreement", $agreement->getId(), $_GET['token'], $agreement);

} else {
    ResultPrinter::printResult("User Cancelled the Approval", null);
}
return $agreement;
```

Changing the date did not solve the problem with the start_date response issue

Thank you again for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

For the date, you could use date('c', time()+210) as per http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Would you mind answering the information as, what was the payment method while creating Billing Agrement. If you used PayPal, you need to click on the approval_url, and complete the flow.

Once done, you need to execute the payment, and then, when you do a get on the Agreement, you would be able to see the state as Active.

Let me know if that fixes this.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for answering but it did not fix it, i added more informations about it !